# Python code works when running normally but not in the debugger - groupby().max().unstack()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am currently using pycharm Community Edition 2022.1
When I run the following code it works with the run command, but not when I try to use the debugger.

```
Logical = all_sites.groupby(["parcel_id","TypologySize"])[['NetProfitPct']].max().unstack()
```

With the Error message "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable.
It appears to be the unstack() step that is causing a problem as removing this step works.

In the above, all_sites is the dataframe and I am trying to return a dataframe with the highest net profit by the parcel id and TypologySize variables.
groupby is a pandas function that enables computation by groups. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

The result before the unstack() function is a dataframe with parcel_id/TypologySize in the index and the one NetProfitPct column.
i.e.

```
1065854/LargeApartments|  0.251
```

Unstack is then supposed to split the index into two separate columns to get the following.

```
1| 1065854 LargeApartments  0.251
```

Does anyone know why this would be happening in the first case, and what my best workaround would be.

Comment: Have you made sure the changes are saved on disk?  It might be using the code currently saved on disk while you have changes that have yet to be saved open in your editor.

Comment: Yes it is saved on the disk, the error in the debugger referred to the exact line. 
I have actually managed a work around with just using reset_index to achieve the same effect but it doesn't explain why I got the behavior that I did.

Comment: You should post your workaround as an answer and accept it so that anyone else who has the same problem might no how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I found using reset_index() instead of unstack worked. i.e.

`Logical = all_sites.groupby(["parcel_id","TypologySize"])[['NetProfitPct']].max().reset_index()  #.unstack()`